# How can I prove that F2 is a Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I have to prove that the set {1,0} is a field. Do I have to go through every 8 possibilities when I want to show associativity or is there an easier way and how do you argue with an infinite set like $\mathbb{R}$ when you want to show that for ex. $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$, with $+$ being the normal addition.

Comment: I just want to show + := M x M -> M ,M = {0,1} and +(0,0) = +(1,1) = 1 ;+(1,0) = +(0,1) = 1 is an abelian group

Comment: $(\Bbb{Z}/2,+)$ is an abelian group, as you know.

Comment: The set $\{0,1\}$ is not a field. This set endowed with appropriate operations is a field. And if you want to prove addition associativity on the reals, you have to define what the reals are.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know what you’re suppose to know or not.

It you write $\mathbb F_2= \mathbb Z /2 \mathbb Z$, then the result is clear. $\mathbb F_2$ is a field as it is the quotient of a ring over a maximal ideal and therefore is a field.

By the way, you’re almost forced to have this background. How do you define $\mathbb F_2$ without it?

Comment: I agree. You either define $F_2$ as $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, or you present a multiplication and addition table. The former allows you to reason it gets its properties from the quotient, and the latter pretty much forces you to do the "brute force" verification of associativity, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Commutativity and associativity for both operations, as well as the distributive law all follow from the fact that these properties are satisfied in $\mathbb{R}$. After all, if you take $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F_2}$ then you can think of $a,b,c$ as of real numbers. Even in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ so of course it is also true if you look at that number mod $2$. (if it is the same number then it also has the same remainder after division by $2$)

Comment: And how do you show that those properties are satisfied in R?

Comment: I always thought of that as axioms to be honest, at least for addition and multiplication of integers.

Comment: @RM777 What are you supposed to know? If I follow your question, you’ll be forced to come back to the construction of $\mathbb R$, which is based on $\mathbb Q$, itself based on $\mathbb Z$... I’m not sure that it’s what you expect or what the person who ask you the question on $\mathbb F_2$ expects.

Comment: Right now this is misleading. Saying that it's true "because it's satisfied in $\mathbb R$ suggests that it has something to do with $F_2$ being a subset of $R$ or a quotient, which it isn't.  Saying it is true in $\mathbb R$ doesn't do anything if there's no connection to $\mathbb R$.  It *is* true because it is a *quotient of $\mathbb Z$*, but that deserves a line or two of justification.

Comment: My question was answered. I am allowed to assume that (R,+,*) is a field. I will now study the construction for R which will prove my assumption.

Comment: $a,b,c\in F_2$ *are not* real numbers. All three of them satisfy $a+a=0$, which is something only $0$ can do in $\mathbb R$.  I think if you rephrased your question in terms of the quotient of $\mathbb Z$ and not $\mathbb R$, your explanation would be ok.

Comment: @rschwieb, yes they are not real numbers. However, you can think of them as real numbers, add (or multiply) with the regular laws of addition (multiplication) and only in the end turn what you get to mod $2$. That works as we know addition and multiplication are well defined operations and doesn't depend on which numbers from the equivalence class we choose.

Comment: @Mark I know what you're trying to say, I'm just trying to point out that the explanation you gave is fraught with pitfalls. Case in point, the OP just posted a comment along the lines of "OK, now I will review the construction of $\mathbb R$" which is an unfortunate thing to be doing. The argument is not hard to "tighten-up" though, which is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Mark What you’re describing is building the quotient field of a subring of the reals, namely $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: True, my explanation was not very formal. Though I knew $\mathbb{F_2}$ is a field long time before I even started learning group theory and had any idea that $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Finite fields are usually learned earlier.

Comment: @Mark **You were told** that $\mathbb F_2$ was a field. **But were you at that time able to prove it** without going in depth in addition and multiplication tables?

Comment: Well, at least the explanation was pretty much the same as I gave in my answer. Maybe it isn't formal proof, but as I know if two integers are equal in $\mathbb{Z}$ then they will be equal mod $2$ as well. The only "problem" here is that we have to think about elements of $\mathbb{F_2}$ as integers to add them. But no, we didn't use addition and multiplication tables for that. It is possible to build a table for $\mathbb{F_2}$ but I don't think one wants to do that for $\mathbb{F_{71}}$ for example, or for an even bigger prime.

Comment: @Mark The second problem is to be sure that a property, let’s say associativity is independent from the representatives of a given class. This is the beauty of defining the quotient.

Comment: Of course it has to be proved that addition and multiplication are well defined and doesn't depend on the choose of representatives. That is the first thing which should be done. Anyway, I agree your answer is better than mine, though it might be above OPs level.